# Unable to get filename/foldername of team drive file using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have been trying to get the filename of a file/folder which is located in my team drive.

I have tried with

```
showAlert(DriveApp.getFolderById('0ANNqmMDkIgpzUk9PVA').getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is good, so

1. Check that you have the complete folder id. If you missed out some characters, it will not work.
2. Check that you have at least viewing permission for the folder.

I successfully tested the following with a public folder:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(
  "Folder name: " + 
  DriveApp.getFolderById('16EbJb18MXxnDrbc0OsMbOk4CBxrT1upM').getName()
);
```

The alert popped up in an open Google Sheets page.[image: Screenshot]

You could also replace `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert` with `Browser.msgBox`

Comment: Where and how do I get complete folder id?

Comment: (1) In Google drive, right-click your folder. (2) select "Get shareable link", a link will appear. (3) The file's id is everything that comes after this: `https://drive.google.com/open?id=`.

Alternatively:
(1) In Google drive, open your folder. (2) Look at the URL. (3) The file's id is everything between `/folders/` and the next `/` or `?`.